# How do i remove "Try again: message after 3rd failed try

Tags: python

I want to remove the `"try again"` message after it fails on the third try.

```
chance=0
a=5
while chance<3:
    guess=int(input("input your number"))
    chance = chance + 1
    if guess==a:
        print("You win")
        break
    else:
        print("Try again")
    if chance>=3:
        print("You are out of chances")
```

Comment: Move the last if into the else and perform the print of "try again" only in *its* else case.

Comment: off-by-one issue: your `chance` count starts with 0, ends at 2. Currently `"You are out of chances"` will never be printed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to correctly place the `if` condition statements as follows:

```
chance=0
a=5
while chance<3:
    guess=int(input("Input your number:\n"))
    chance = chance + 1
    if guess==a:
        print("You win")
        break
    else:
        if chance>=3:
            print("YOu are out of chances")
        else:
            print("Try again")
```

**Output:**'

```
Input your number:
0
Try again
Input your number:
0
Try again
Input your number:
0
YOu are out of chances
```

Comment: Do we need `else` after break. Wouldn't a separate `if..else` be simpler here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding 1 extra condition will work

```py
chance = 0
a = 5
while chance < 3:
    guess = int(input("input your number: "))
    chance = chance + 1
    if guess == a:
        print("You win")
        break
    elif chance < 3:
        print("Try again")
    else:
        print("You are out of chances")
```

**I'll implement like this**

```py
chance = 0
a = 5
while True:
    guess = int(input("input your number"))
    chance = chance + 1
    if guess == a:
        print("You win")
        break
    elif chance < 3:
        print("Try again")
    else:
        print("You are out of chances")
        break
```

Comment: @hc_dev you're right, break is not needed for the first program but needed for the second one, Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see the `while True:` which otherwise would bear danger of infinite-loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The third try is when `chance == 2`.

Then your last condition `if chance >= 3:` **will never be reached** because the while-loop exits before, when `chance < 3`.

```
chance = 0  # why not define max chances instead
while chance < 3:
    # ask to guess
    chance = chance + 1   # consider for-loop where you don't need to count
    if guess==a:
        # win and exit        
    else:
        print("Try again")

    if chance >= 3:  # will never be greater 3 because while-condition
        print("You are out of chances")
```

See above, how chance-counting and the proper arrangement of if-else-if makes the loop-body long and complex plus distracts from the loop's main-purpose.

### Solutions

Most crucial is the exit-condition of the while-loop. Defined properly it saves you from a `break`.

Then, either try to have `if .. elif .. else` for **3 outcomes** like:

```
guess = None  # init guess
chances = 3   # max chances defined once

# while continues if guess not matching and chances left 
while not (guess == a or chances <= 0):
    guess = int(input("input your number"))
    chances = chances - 1  # count down

    # output one of the 3
    if guess == a:   # same condition that was negated in while
        print("You win")
    elif chances <= 0:  # same condition that was negated in while
        print("You are out of chances")
    else:
        print("Try again. " + str(chances) + " left.")
```

Or make the exit-condition even more expressive and extract the 2 exit-states out of the loop-body, towards the end:

#### Loop reduced to retries

Let's make the loop express its only purpose, tries:

```
guess = None  # init guess
chances = 3   # max chances defined once

# while continues if guess not matching and chances left 
while guess != a and chances > 0:
    guess = int(input("input your number"))
    if guess != a:
        chances = chances - 1  # count down
        print("Try again. " + str(chances) + " left.")

# output one of the 2 final states
if guess == a:   # condition that exits while
    print("You win")
else:  # other condition that exits while
    print("You are out of chances")
```

**Benefits:**
This has an expressive while-header expressing the retry condition and a pretty short and simple loop body. Afterwards the 2 *post-conditions* (exit-conditions) are evaluated. The `else:` can also be formulated to cite the other exist-condition (`elif chances <= 0:`).

#### For-loop

Another variant would be a **for-loop** to focus on retries in the loop-header but with a complex body: `break` and **separate chances-test**:

```
max_chances = 3  # define the max chances once, here: 3
for chance in range(max_chances):  # e.g. chance counts from 0 to 2
    guess = int(input("input your number"))

    # win test
    if guess == a:
        print("You win")
        break

    # chance test
    if chance + 1 == max_chances:
        print("You are out of chances")
    else:
        print(f"Try again. {max_chances - (chance + 1)} chance(s) left.")
```

Note the separate `if`: After the `break` the game and the loop is over and exits. If not won, we continue with the next `if` branching into one of our 2 alternative outputs.